# How to enable automatic retries for Mongo Socket exception?

Tags: mongodb, retry-logic

I'm running a spring boot gradle project. Spring boot version is 2.3.2.RELEASE, MongoDB version is 4.0.5.

Per below site, retryable writes are enabled by default from MongoDB 3.6+ https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/

I saw the following exceptions in the project, MongoReadException and MongoWriteException while reading/saving to the mongo database. I would like to know if these exceptions are automatically retried starting Spring boot 2.3.2.RELEASE.

Below are the exceptions I wanted to retry,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception sending message; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Prematurely reached end of stream; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
```

To try it out, I created a spring boot demo app in my local that tries to save a document to a database whose uri is provided with invalid value in the properties file. I get MongoTimeoutException on save document which is as expected. However, I don't see any retries on the **save** operation.

I also tried to add the property retryWrites=true to the connection uri, it didn't work
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://XXX:XXXX@invalid-server:5555/dummyDB?**&retrywrites=true**

Does anyone know how to enable the retries ? How do I test it locally ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Below is the exception stacktrace with MongoSocketOpenException. I would like to test if this exception is auto retried, however, it's not.

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]] with root cause

com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:177) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:147) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:98) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:278) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:202) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1008) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:469) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:452) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:446) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$15(MongoTemplate.java:1442) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:566) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1436) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1236) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1168) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:85) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Add full exception report to the question, code you are using, what you are expecting to be retried.

Comment: @D.SM Thanks for your reply. Please see the updated post above with the exception details. I'd like to see the automatic retries on MongoReadException or MongoWriteException in my local. I wasn't sure how to reproduce these errors in my local. So, started with a sample spring boot that tries to connect to an invalid mongo uri. My expectation is that, MongoTimeoutException should also be retried once. Also, please suggest any alternatives on how to handle the retries on the mongo exceptions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retries apply to operations like reads and writes.

Operations are only sent once the driver successfully connects to the server(s) you indicate in connection string/client configuration.

Your server is not accessible by the client therefore that connection isn't working therefore no operations can be performed therefore the concept of operation retries doesn't apply.

The monitoring *is* retried automatically, once you fix the connectivity issue between the client and the server (or start the server) the client will recognize this automatically.